# Getting Invalid Grant on OAuth2 authorization_code post request for Google Play Billing purchase verification

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, play-billing-library

I'm trying to implement purchase verification in my backend as the [Google-Play-Billing docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Verify) recommend. Following this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get) for subscription purchase verification, it tells me I must make a get request to that URL ([Purchases.subscriptions: get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get)) with my android app's **package name**, **subscription_id**, and **purchase token**. However, before I can make a get request to that URL, I must authorize my backend server for API requests. So, following the link in that documentation to [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization), I began following those steps. I created an **OAuth 2.0 client ID**, then generated the initial refresh token by going to the next url in my browser. My *client_id* was set to my **OAuth 2.0 client ID** that was just generated, and my *redirect_uri* was set to **urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob**, which I received from the JSON file I downloaded from the **Google API Console**. I successfully retrieved my initial refresh token and put it in my backend code.

Now the goal is to make a successful purchase in my android app, then send a post request to my backend with the necessary parameters. This part works just fine. However, when following the next steps of the [authorization documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization), the part where it says to "*Exchange this code for an access and refresh token pair by sending a POST request to...*" in order to get my **access_code**, I set the fields to what the docs say to set the fields to, but my request comes back as a 400 error with the error message: "**invalid_grant**". I don't understand why I am receiving this error.

Here is my post request code:

```
List <NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList <>();
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", initial_code));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", client_id));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", client_secret));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", redirect_uri));

RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.IGNORE_COOKIES).build();
HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig);

try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build()) {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        final StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println("Response returned: " + statusLine.getStatusCode() + " - " + EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        }
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: After more research I'm wondering if need to set the access_type of my client_id to `offline`? However I cannot figure out how to actually do this.

Comment: Okay, after more research, I realize that the redirect_uri that I'm setting is meant to open a browser for manual copy/pasting of the authorization_code. I don't need this to redirect a user anywhere because this is all happening in the backend. So what do I set my redirect_uri to when I don't want to redirect anywhere but where the request originated from?

Comment: Seriously! Can nobody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out my problem. I need to be faster about making that first post request to exchange the initial refresh_token for and access_code and new refresh_token. That new refresh_token will end up being my permanent refresh_token for all future api requests. My problem was that the initial refresh_token kept expiring before I made my initial post request. I didn't realize it would expire in 1 hour, and so I kept using the same initial refresh_token without realizing that it was expired.

I followed the rest of the steps on google's docs, and now my backend server is successfully validating my in app subscription purchases.